# Normalize euclidean distance eigenfaces recognition method

Tags: image, opencv, face-recognition, euclidean-distance

I'm training a model with the following function and the following recognition method

```
resized_test_img = 'a.jpg'
label, confidence = eigenfaces_recognizer.predict(resized_test_img)
```

the output of the confidence give me the euclidean distance value which gives me values up to 10000.

I can normalize these values from 0 to 100%?

Comment: while you can apply some heuristic, like: `pc = (1oooo - dist)/100` , note, that the distance distribution is not linear, and you cannot expect to get an "exact" percentage

Comment: and where i get the value dist?

Comment: the distance from your prediction ("confidence", a clear misnomer here)

Comment: and again, distances are not probabilities, and imo, you're on the wrong boat